# Show content from plugin on index

Tags: plugins, theme-development

I am fairly new to WordPress Theming and you don't need to provide me a complete answer for this, but rather a nudge into the right direction, as I'm still trying to understand the basic concepts of this area.

Basically, I have a plugin [Events Manager](http://wp-events-plugin.com). And parts of this plugin, the list of upcoming events, I want to show on the Index of my custom Theme.

So far, I've been kind of following [this documentation](http://wp-events-plugin.com/documentation/using-template-files/) page, so I've taken the `events-list.php` file from the template folder of the plugin and put it in my custom theme folder ( `/plugins/events-manager/templates/templates`, as described on the above linked page) and tried to fetch it with `get_template_part()`, to no success.

Again, maybe (probably) I'm just not fully understanding a basic theming concept here, so just an advice on where I need to go looking for should probably suffice.

Comment: Hi patrick. Would you mind describing your issue? _"Not working"_ is not really a question, you should describe what is happening, including errors, PHP logs, etc.

Comment: @JackJohansson, thanks for cleaning up the post and for your comment. With "trying to fetch it with `get_template_part()`, to no success" I actually meant, that nothing is happening, really. The part on the page, where I expect the events-list to appear, stays empty. There are no errors thrown.

Comment: you can't use get_template this way http://buildwpyourself.com/get-template-part/, instead you might want to use a shortcode in your template. the plugin documentation might tell you how to call a shortcode function directly, which is more efficient than using something like `echo do_shortcode('[some-short-code-and-params]');`.

Comment: @inarilo thanks for the suggestion, will look into it!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your documentation link under Common Mistakes:

> Wrong folder path – Files within the templates folder are not put
>   within
>   wp-content/themes/twentyten/plugins/events-manager/templates/templates/, note the extra templates folder in this path compared to the previous
>   one.

Use `/plugins/events-manager/templates/` instead. I.e. you need to copy files inside the plugin's templates folder to your theme, not that first templates folder.

The plugin should then fetch these files automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should've mentioned, that I actually tried this first, before moving them to `templates/templates`, it doesn't change anything, though